# If $X$ is independent of $Y$, is it true that $E(f(X)|Y) = E(f(X))$ for any function $f$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

If $X$ is independent of $Y$, is it true that $E(f(X)|Y) = E(f(X))$ for any function $f$? I cannot think of a specific example but am not able to prove it either. The best I have been able to do so far is to recognize that it suffices to show that $f(X)$ is independent of $Y$. From a measure theoretic standpoint, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X \in A, Y \in B)= P(X \in A) P(Y \in B)$ for Borel sets $A,B$. Then, I have that $P(f(X) \in C, Y \in B) = P(X \in f^{-1}(C), Y \in B)$, but don't know what to do from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is true for an arbitrary measurable $f$. For if $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets, then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(f(X)\in A,Y\in B) &= \mathbb P(X\in f^{-1}(A),Y\in B)\\ &=\mathbb P(X\in f^{-1}(A))\mathbb P(Y\in B),\end{align}
so that $f(X)$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my measure theory is a bit bad, but can I ask why how you got the last line? The way I did it, I was stuck at the following: since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X \in A, Y \in B)= P(X \in A) P(Y \in B)$ for Borel sets $A,B$. Then, I have that $P(f(X) \in C, Y \in B) = P(X \in f^{-1}(C), Y \in B)$, but don't how to reconcile the borel set $A$ and $f^{-1}(C)$. Thanks!

Comment: Since $f$ is measurable, $f^{-1}(C)$ is a Borel set.

Comment: I see, so am I right to say that I should have formulated my understanding of independence as: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X \in A, Y \in B)= P(X \in A) P(Y \in B)$ for ANY Borel sets $A,B$?

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the $\sigma$-algebras generated by the random variables are independent, that is, for $E\in\sigma(X)$, $F\in\sigma(Y)$, $\mathbb P(E\cap F) = \mathbb P(E)\mathbb P(F)$.